# onfocus on Form isn't working

Tags: forms, onfocus

I was just checking my newest website creation today & was making sure the form was ok & for some reason the onfocus of the street address is not working, the onblur works fine and all the other text inputs work with the onfocus & onblur. I have looked at the code for 30 minutes and for the life of my cannot figure out what is wrong. I need a fresh pair of eyes to check and see what I did wrong. Below is the code, the Street Address is the one that wont work. (onfocus)

```
<h2>Contact Form</h2>

<label for="name"></label><input type="text" name="name" size="26" value="Name" style="color: #775594;" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Name'}" onfocus="if(this.value=='Name'){this.value=''}" /><br /> 
<label for="email"></label><input type="text" name="email" size="26" value="Email" style="color: #775594;" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Email'}" onfocus="if(this.value=='Email'){this.value=''}" /><br /> 
<label for="phone"></label><input type="text" name="phone" maxlength="13" size="26" value="Phone" style="color: #775594;" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Phone'}" onfocus="if(this.value=='Phone'){this.value=''}" /><br /> 
<label for="street"></label><input type="text" name="street" size="26" value="Street Address" style="color: #775594;" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Street Address'}" onfocus="if(this.value=='Street Adress'){this.value=''}" /><br /> 
<label for="city"></label><input type="text" name="city" size="10" value="City" style="color: #775594;" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='City'}" onfocus="if(this.value=='City'){this.value=''}" /> 
<label for="zip"></label><input type="text" name="zip" maxlength="5" size="10" value="Zip Code" style="color: #775594;" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Zip Code'}" onfocus="if(this.value=='Zip Code'){this.value=''}" /><br />

<p class="center"><input type="submit" value="Send" /></p>
</fieldset></form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a typo:

```
onfocus="if(this.value=='Street Adress')
```

Address is missing a d.

Comment: AHH omg thank you!! It's soo irritating when I can't find out what I did wrong. Thank you

Comment: No prob, know the feeling. It might be worth it to generate these fields with a function in javascript. Then you could avoid having to type each field description twice.